# Testing 3 Conditions

Tags: php, html

I have 3 true conditions:

**EDITED:**

```
 #sell-status-no {
   background-color: #fe220b;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 240px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#sell-status-yes {
   background-color: #25b116;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 240px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}

 if (($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage >= 30.00) || ($profit 
     < 10.00 && $markup_percentage >= 30.00) ||
     ($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage < 30.00)){
        $status = "YES";
        $div_id = 'sell-status-yes';
    }
 else $status = "no"; {
        $div_id = 'sell-status-no';
    }

   <div id="<?php echo $div_id; ?>"> 
            <h2>Sell Status: <?php echo $status; ?> <h2>
        </div>
```

Basically if any of the conditions are true, I output a div with a green background with the words YES.  If false, the box is red and the word NO is used.

However, whenever I encounter a situation where the $profit < 10 && $markup_percentage is > 30, I end up with the false condition (red box and a NO)??

I am not sure why this is the case so any help or a better solution to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Note that this line is not part of the `if` - `else` part and will always be executed: `$div_id = 'sell-status-no';`

Comment: Not really related to the question, but am I correct in seeing that as long as `$profit > 10`, `$markup_percentage` can be anything (both `>=30` and `<30`)? It seems like you could rewrite this if a lot easier as `if($profit >= 10 || $markup_percentage >= 30)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braces issue. If you will format code you will see this

```
if (
    ($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage >= 30.00) 
        || 
    ($profit < 10.00 && $markup_percentage >= 30.00) 
        ||
    ($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage < 30.00)){
        $status = "YES";
        $div_id = 'sell-status-yes';
    }
 else $status = "no"; 

{
    $div_id = 'sell-status-no';
}
```

Try changing it to

```
if (
    ($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage >= 30.00) 
        || 
    ($profit < 10.00 && $markup_percentage >= 30.00) 
        ||
    ($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage < 30.00)){
        $status = "YES";
        $div_id = 'sell-status-yes';
    }
 else {
    $status = "no"; 
    $div_id = 'sell-status-no';
}
```

Also you can simplify condition to

```
if ($profit >= 10.00 || $markup_percentage >= 30.00){
        $status = "YES";
        $div_id = 'sell-status-yes';
    }
 else {
    $status = "no"; 
    $div_id = 'sell-status-no';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried this amendment but still end up with the red box with NO.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'else' condition is the statement

```
$status = "no";
```

You then have the spurious scope block:

```
{
    $div_id = 'sell-status-no';
}
```

Which will always be executed.

Note also that your conditional logic can be simplified with [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra):

```
if (($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage >= 30.00) || 
     ($profit < 10.00 && $markup_percentage >= 30.00) ||
     ($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage < 30.00)){
```

is the same as

```
if (($markup_percentage >= 30.00) ||
     ($profit >= 10.00 && $markup_percentage < 30.00))
```

**Edit** As per mleko's full answer, the code

```
else $status = "no"; {
        $div_id = 'sell-status-no';
    }
```

is wrong and misleading. The two statements must BOTH be in the else block:

```
else {
    $status = "no"; 
    $div_id = 'sell-status-no';
}
```

Comment: nice use of 'spurious'

Comment: I've signed up with English.Stackexchange ;-)

Comment: thanks for getting back StuartLC.  I see that the conditional logic needs simplified, however I am not quite sure what I need to fix in the else condition?

Comment: mleko has the full code - `$status = "no"; {` must be `{ $status = "no"; `. Once you have that working switch out the if with the simplified code above?

Comment: I've edited. You need to give mleko the tick - he spelt it out clearer than I did.

Comment: Thanks again StuartLC, much appreciated!!  Also admire your selflessness :)